# interfacing of python and arduino

Tags: python, python-2.7, arduino

We are interfacing ardiuno and python , and we need to send our signal from python to ardiuno  after different intervals , for that we used a loop to send the data and to receive the data, but we are not getting the signal from python in loop. 
However when we used the same code , for sending the signal from python to ardiuno without using loop, it worked fine.

how to use it in loop 
using arduino uno

this is our code

```
 int ra = 3;
 int ya = 4;
 int ga = 5;
 int rb = 6;
 int yb = 7;
 int gb = 8;
 int x1=0;
 int x2=0;
 int x=0;
 int led=10;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(ra,OUTPUT);
pinMode(ya,OUTPUT);
pinMode(ga,OUTPUT);
pinMode(rb,OUTPUT);
pinMode(yb,OUTPUT);
pinMode(gb,OUTPUT);
pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
if(Serial.available()){
x2=Serial.parseInt();
 //x2++;

Serial.end();}



if ((x2>=0)&&(x2<=9))
 { 
   x=x2;
   switch(x)
   {
    case 0 :
    digitalWrite(ga,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rb,HIGH);

    delay(8000);
    digitalWrite(ga,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(rb,LOW);
    //digitalWrite(ra,HIGH);
    delay(50);

     digitalWrite(gb,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ra,HIGH);

    delay(12000);
    digitalWrite(gb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ra,LOW);
    delay(50);



    break;


    case 1:
    digitalWrite(ga,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rb,HIGH);

    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(ga,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(rb,LOW);
    //digitalWrite(ra,HIGH);
    delay(50);
     digitalWrite(gb,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ra,HIGH);

    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(gb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ra,LOW);
    break;

    case 2:
    digitalWrite(ga,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rb,HIGH);

    delay(9000);
    digitalWrite(ga,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(rb,LOW);
   delay(50);
    digitalWrite(gb,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ra,HIGH);

    delay(9000);
    digitalWrite(gb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ra,LOW);
    break;

    case 3:
    digitalWrite(ga,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rb,HIGH);

    delay(12000);
    digitalWrite(ga,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(rb,LOW);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(gb,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ra,HIGH);

    delay(12000);
    digitalWrite(gb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ra,LOW);
    break;

    case 4:
    digitalWrite(ga,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rb,HIGH);

    delay(15000);
    digitalWrite(ga,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(rb,LOW);
      delay(50);
      digitalWrite(gb,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ra,HIGH);

    delay(15000);
    digitalWrite(gb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ra,LOW); 
    break;

    case 5:
    digitalWrite(ga,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rb,HIGH);


    delay(18000);
    digitalWrite(ga,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(rb,LOW);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(gb,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ra,HIGH);


    delay(18000);
    digitalWrite(gb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ra,LOW);
    break;

    case 6:
    digitalWrite(ga,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rb,HIGH);

    delay(2100);
    digitalWrite(ga,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(rb,LOW);
   delay(50);
   digitalWrite(gb,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ra,HIGH);

    delay(2100);
    digitalWrite(gb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ra,LOW);

    break;

    case 7:
    digitalWrite(ga,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rb,HIGH);

    delay(24000);
    digitalWrite(ga,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(rb,LOW);
   delay(50);
   digitalWrite(gb,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ra,HIGH);

    delay(24000);
    digitalWrite(gb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ra,LOW);


    break;

    case 8:
    digitalWrite(ga,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rb,HIGH);

    delay(28000);
    digitalWrite(ga,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(rb,LOW);
   delay(50);
   digitalWrite(gb,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ra,HIGH);

    delay(28000);
    digitalWrite(gb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ra,LOW);
    break;

    case 9:
    digitalWrite(ga,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rb,HIGH);

    delay(30000);
    digitalWrite(ga,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(rb,LOW);
   delay(50);
   digitalWrite(gb,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ra,HIGH);

    delay(30000);
    digitalWrite(gb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yb,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ya,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(yb,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ya,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ra,LOW);
     break;
     }}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the Arduino's Serial port after reading data from it by using the Serial.end() inside the loop function.
If you remove/comment the Serial.end() statement, you will keep receiving data on Arduino's serial port.

Refer https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/End

Also, I believe you are using the pyserial library in Python for serial communication (it makes our life a little easier) :)

Let us know if it works.